# Can I install wubi ubuntu 12.04 in a partition (D:) other than Windows Partition (C:)?

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot, partitioning, wubi

I want to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS using Wubi. I already have Windows xp in my system. I want to add Ubuntu (Wubi) for dual boot. My system is like this:

- Windows (C:) 19 Gb (free=2GB)
- Drive 2 (D:) 19 Gb (free=19Gb) >> I want to install wubi ubuntu here.
- Drive 3 (E:) 17 Gb (free=10Gb)
- Drive 4 (F:) 17 Gb (free=10Gb)

My only concern is if I choose installation drive as D: instead of C:, then will I still be able to boot into Windows?

Also if I use Wubi, will my bootloader get overwritten?

Also, does an install using Wubi cause an Ubuntu environment that requires more system resources than usual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## For LiveCD installation

When installing Ubuntu, choose the option to **install alongside Windows**.

The Windows bootloader will be changed from the Windows Bootloader to [Grub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB). This is a third pary loader which searches your hard  disk drives looking for different Operating Systems and should see both you windows and Ubuntu installations.

## For wubi installation

It should be straight forward with no problems.

To see a video tutorial visit [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=00N0DsD9sog)

Comment: Thank you, but in wubi screenshots, i can't see the **install alongside Windows** option anywhere??

Comment: Take a look at the extra info I added at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your talking about the Windows installer, Wubi, I believe it should be fine installing it in D:, and it should't mess up your bootloader.