# How to install Ubuntu on Windows 7 PC?

Tags: boot, windows-7, 13.04

I am trying to install Ubuntu on my PC but it doesn't show the boot window.

When I started my PC and went in the disc clicked on Wubi, it showed demo and full installation.

I clicked on that.

Then, there were 3 options. I clicked on help boot from CD but it started installing something and then showed an error: 
`COULD NOT RETRIEVE THE INSTALLATION FILES` so I cancelled that.

What should I do?

How do I install Ubuntu on my Windows 7 PC?

Comment: Could you make your question clearer by adding some images of your screen?

Comment: There is a detailed explanation here: [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/q/6328/107450).  If this isn't working for you please provide more details: specific error messages or screen shot showing where it is going wrong.  Also note for Ubuntu 13.04 (and future versions) Wubi is not recommended and dual boot is preferred. You can still use Wubi with 12.04 however.

Comment: @Dineshkumar the user does not have the privileges to add images to posts yet (50 reputation points required)

Comment: @WarrenHill if you have an answer, please add it to the answers rather than as a comment. It could help others find the correct answer to their questions in the future.

Comment: @SimplySimon : My comment isn't an answer its a link to a possible duplicate and a request for more information if it doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

The problem I believe is because wubi is designed to be run from Windows, where as, LiveCD should be loaded and run from CD at boot.

You can download and burn Ubuntu's LiveCD from the [Ubuntu Website](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

Please see an answer I gave this morning [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/325613/can-i-install-wubi-ubuntu-12-04-in-a-partition-d-other-than-windows-partition/325617#325617)

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem trying to make boot files in windows7 , but if you change your boot setting from bios menu , and change the first boot device from hard drive or anything else to cd drive (or dvd drive), then it will boot easily and you won't have to do anything with wubi in windows , 
i hope this will help you!